# My changes are not ending up in the go app. What's going on with go?

Tags: go

I'm new to go.

I have cloned this project: [oauth2_proxy][1]
I'm wanting to add another provider.  So I created the provider file in providers.  Added the provider name to the providers switch statement.
However, when I build the resulting binary, the provider keeps falling back to google.

It seems my provider has not been added.  I suspect that go build might be pulling the providers from github and ignoring my local changes.  Would that be right?  How do you build this thing?

I'm building with `go build` because ./dist.sh script didn't work for me.  I'm managing to produce a binary.  But it doesn't appear my code file ended up in it.  I know this because when I grep for "google" or "linkedin" or any of the provider names on the resulting binary it says: `Binary file oauth2_proxy matches`.  But for my own provider, there is no match.

It's probably got something to do with the way I'm compiling the app.  How do I do that? no instructions on the github page for doing that are provided.  Sorry for my ignorance.  I'm coming from a c++ background which is more logical.  Go seems to pick up dependancies automagically!?

---

Following suggestions from @Topo

```
matthewh@xen:~/dev/oauth2_proxy$ export GOPATH=`pwd`
matthewh@xen:~/dev/oauth2_proxy$ rm -rf src
matthewh@xen:~/dev/oauth2_proxy$ go get ./...
go install: no install location for directory /home/matthewh/dev/oauth2_proxy outside GOPATH
    For more details see: 'go help gopath'
go install: no install location for directory /home/matthewh/dev/oauth2_proxy/api outside GOPATH
    For more details see: 'go help gopath'
go install: no install location for directory /home/matthewh/dev/oauth2_proxy/cookie outside GOPATH
    For more details see: 'go help gopath'
go install: no install location for directory /home/matthewh/dev/oauth2_proxy/providers outside GOPATH
    For more details see: 'go help gopath'

src/cloud.google.com/go/internal/retry.go:21:2: cannot find package "github.com/googleapis/gax-go" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/googleapis/gax-go (from $GOROOT)
    /home/matthewh/dev/oauth2_proxy/src/github.com/googleapis/gax-go (from $GOPATH)
src/google.golang.org/api/internal/settings.go:22:2: cannot find package "google.golang.org/grpc" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/google.golang.org/grpc (from $GOROOT)
    /home/matthewh/dev/oauth2_proxy/src/google.golang.org/grpc (from $GOPATH)
src/google.golang.org/api/transport/dial.go:30:2: cannot find package "google.golang.org/grpc/credentials" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/credentials (from $GOROOT)

 ...

  [1]: https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy
```

Comment: It doesn't pull the providers form anywhere, if you are using go build it's using the local files. I'm not familiar with the code you are using but try doing `go build ./...`. If your provider is in a subpackage it might be using the latest compiled version of the package but the command with the `./...` will rebuild the entire project and the dependencies.

Comment: I don't recall how I got it to even pull in dependancies.  If I simply do go `build ./...`  it prints out dependancy errors.  e.g.  oauthproxy.go:17:2: cannot find package "github.com/18F/hmacauth" in any of: ...

Comment: Do `go get ./...` and then `go build ./...`. Go get will fetch the dependencies from github. Not sure how you compiled it the first time without them.

Comment: What does ./... after build and get mean compared to . ?  it gives different results

Comment: @Topo - I followed your go get and go build suggestion after first cleaning up the existing src directory.  Unfortunately, there are lots of errors.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do as @jeevatkm said. The go tool only works as expected if you have it configured correctly. Take a look at https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I just did `go get -v github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy` on my machine.

Verbose Details: http://pasted.co/60e2b56d

Binary is produced under `$GOPATH/bin/oauth2_proxy`.

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jeeva  staff    10M Jul 11 19:02 oauth2_proxy
```

---

Let's start from basis. First setup your Go workspace ([How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)) pick a directory for GOPATH.

For example: /Users/matt/dev

```
export GOPATH=/Users/matt/dev
```

Then do `go get` to get the `oauth2_proxy`. Typically go get is git clone of that repository.

```
go get github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy
```

It will get the source code and runs `go install`. After successful execution of this command. You will see binary file in `$GOPATH/bin`.

Now modified the source code as you need and run go install to build the binary.

```
go install github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy

OR
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy
go install
```

---

If you would like to manually instead of `go get`. Then pick a directory for `GOPATH` and export it (as mentioned above) then

```
mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/bitly
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/bitly
git clone https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy.git
cd oauth2_proxy
go get ./...
go install
```

Now binary will be in `$GOPATH/bin`.

Comment: I originally used git clone.    `go get github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy` fails to produce a folder.  And so nothing happens.  Go install then fails silently.  I'll try the manual step

Comment: Did you setup GOPATH correctly? Also you can added `-v` to see what's going on with `go get -v github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy`.

Comment: Yep, I copied your instructions exactly.  I tried it again in a different path and it now seems to do something.   Can you tell me what is this src/github.com biz about?   why does your code need to be there?  why I can't I git clone the thing, then edit the files and build.  When I tried to build with first a go get and go build it would grab the files from github.  Hense loose all my local changes.  What backward design is this?

Comment: `github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy` is called package import path. Good read [here](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#ImportPaths)

Comment: I updated answer with further info, please have a look.

Comment: @Matt just because you don't understand it doesn't mean it's a "backward design". Familiarize yourself with the basics of the Go toolchain, it might help.

Comment: I got it working.  It's backward because it's not intuitive.  It appeared to be building the code but was silently grabbing stuff in the background and building that instead. It goes against the grain of every other system out there.  You might say it's forward, it's annoying that's what it is.  Now that I know, at least I can work with it.  I just found it an irritation to get going quickly.